# Set max length on Recurly JS fields

Tags: javascript, recurly

I'm using Recurly.js v4.0.1 and I'm trying to set the max length to 2 on the month and year field like in [this example](https://kale-krate.herokuapp.com/subscribe-minimal), however I can't seem to find how to set it?

Answer (score 4):

I am the author of Recurly.js -- the example you've linked to is an implementation of Recurly.js v3.x, which used native HTML fields, and thus supported the max length attribute natively. Recurly.js v4 implements fields within iframes to bolster form security -- but with this come some hoops to implementing native html field behaviors.

On that note, I have created an issue on the github repo to create this feature in v4 -- look for it to be implemented soon!

https://github.com/recurly/recurly-js/issues/238

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I didn't know if I was missing something obvious.

Comment: How to actually do this? I don't see this in Recurly.js docs, lnk to example above is down, 238 issue don't have any code and I cannot find corresponding commit because commits for 4.3.0 don't have anything remotely like it. So, how to do this?